# Error installing ORB-SLAM2 on Windows

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm interested in ORB-SLAM2, So I searched and found this site
https://github.com/Phylliida/orbslam-windows <<

so I read the README file and copied it, but I found these errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BH4J.jpg)

I already installed OPENCV on windows and I set up the environment variables well.

How can I fix errors?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting OpenCV_DIR in CMakeLists.txt
`SET("OpenCV_DIR" "C:/opencv")`

If you want an automated installation, build setup for ORB-SALM2, we have it in [this repo](https://github.com/paul-michalik/ORB_SLAM2), `scripts\windows\bootstrap.bat`builds opencv and dependencies using vcpkg and `build.bat` compiles ORB-SLAM2. Bootstrap usually takes time for first time!!

Answer (score 1):

1.Adding the variable to the system path like [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#set-the-opencv-enviroment-variable-and-add-it-to-the-systems-path).

2.Setting the variable by the cmake-gui.Then reconfigure.

3.Setting the include and lib path about opencv in the CMakeLists.txt manually.