# ORB-SLAM2 openCV installation error

Tags: opencv, cmake, ubuntu-14.04, orb, slam

I am trying out ORB SLAM2 for further processes of pose estimation. I m installing it in Ubuntu and after installing python, openGL, openCV, C++ compiler, Pangolin, Eigen3, BLAS and LAPACK, I am getting a make error while I install DBoW2. 
The error is as follows.

```
 root@wehubs:/src/orbslam2/DBoW2/build# cmake ..
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
DLib library not found in the system, it will be downloaded on build
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /src/orbslam2/DBoW2/build
root@wehubs:/src/orbslam2/DBoW2/build# 
root@wehubs:/src/orbslam2/DBoW2/build# make
[  6%] Performing update step for 'DLib'
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
[ 13%] Performing configure step for 'DLib'
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /src/orbslam2/DBoW2/build/dependencies/src/DLib-build
[ 20%] Performing build step for 'DLib'
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DLib.dir/src/DVision/BRIEF.cpp.o
In file included from /src/orbslam2/DBoW2/build/dependencies/src/DLib/src/DVision/BRIEF.cpp:13:0:
/src/orbslam2/DBoW2/build/dependencies/src/DLib/include/DVision/BRIEF.h:32:28: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/DLib.dir/src/DVision/BRIEF.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/DLib.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [dependencies/src/DLib-stamp/DLib-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DLib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: It looks like CMake cannot find `opencv` include files.

Comment: Try setting OpenCV directory, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882262/3460461)

Comment: Check this pull requset https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2/pull/790/files